# Getting rid of duplicates from a pair of corresponding lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates

This is a program that I recently made. The goal of this code is to a pair of corresponding lists. So `randomStringpt1[0]` corresponds to `randomStringpt2[0]`. I want to compare `randomStringpt1[0]` and `randomString2[0]` to the rest of the pairs that the user gave in the randomStrings. But after using this code, it looks like I have duplicated each pair many times, which is the opposite of what I was looking for. I was thinking of using a dictionary, but then realized that a dictionary key could only have one value, which wouldn't help my case if the user used a number twice. Does anyone know how I can reduce the duplicates?
(The tests I have been running have been with the numbers `randomStringpt1 = [1,3,1,1,3]` and `randomStringpy2 = [2,4,2,3,4]`
)

```
randomStringpt1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #Pair of strings that correspond to each other("1,2,3,4,5" doesn't actually matter)
randomStringpt2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(randomStringpt1)):
    randomStringpt1[i] = input("Values for the first string: ")
    randomStringpt2[i] = input("Corresponding value for the second string: ")
print(randomStringpt1) #numbers that the user chose for the first number of the pair
print(randomStringpt2) #numbers that the user chose for the second number of the pair
newStart = []
newEnd = []
for num1 in range(len(randomStringpt1)):
    for num2 in range(len(randomStringpt1)):
        if (int(randomStringpt1[num1]) != int(randomStringpt1[num2]) and int(randomStringpt2[num1]) != int(randomStringpt2[num2])):
            newStart.append(randomStringpt1[num1]) # Adding the pairs that aren't equal to each other to a new list
            newEnd.append(randomStringpt2[num1])
            newStart.append(randomStringpt1[num2])
            newEnd.append(randomStringpt2[num2])
        # else: 
        #   print("The set of numbers from the randomStrings of num1 are not equal to the ones in num2")

print(newStart)
print(newEnd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's analyze the 2 bugs in your code,
the if condition inside the loop is true every time a pair compares to a different one. this means for your example it should output
`[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]`
`[2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]`
since you compare every pair to any other pair that exists. But your output is different because you append both pairs every time and getting a very big result, so you shouldn't append the num2 pairs.

Now, from what you described that you want, you should loop every pair and check if it already exists in the output list. So the for loop part can change like this

```
filtered = []
for pair in zip(randomStringpt1,randomStringpt2):
    if pair not in filtered:
        filtered.append(pair) # Adding the pairs that aren't equal to each other to a new list
```

the zip function takes the 2 lists and for every loop it returns 2 values one from each list the first value pair, then the second values and goes on. the filtered list will be in the following format `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3)]`

Alternative it can be as a one liner like this:

```
filtered = list(dict.fromkeys(zip(randomStringpt1, randomStringpt2)))
```

using the dictionary to identify unique elements and then turn it back into a list
after all that you can get the original format of the lists you had in your code by splitting them like this

```
newStart = [pair[0] for pair in filtered]
newEnd = [pair[1] for pair in filtered]
```

Finally i should tell you to read a little more on python and it's for loops, since the `range(len(yourlist))` is not the python intended way to loop over lists, as python for loops are equivalent to for each loops on other languages and iterate over the list for you instead on relying in a value to get list elements like `yourlist[value]`.